# Eclipse DLTK and Ruby Fast Debugger

Tags: ruby, eclipse, debugging, rubygems, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to debug Ruby scripts with Eclipse ([DLTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_languages_toolkit) installed) on a Windows Vista x64 machine and Ruby 1.92 environment.

I installed ruby-debug19, ruby-debug-base19, ruby-debug-ide19 gems, but I still can't debug Ruby scripts with Eclipse. dlt it says the following,

> Debugging Engine not started The 'Fast Ruby Debugger (ruby-debug)' is selected, but the 'ruby-debug' gem doesn't seem to be installed in the selected Ruby Interpreter (C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe)

I also added the `c:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems` folder to the system library paths of the Ruby interpreter settings in Eclipse.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I had to do the following:

```
$ gem install ruby-debug
$ gem install ruby-debug-base
$ gem install ruby-debug-ide
```

Might this also work on Windows (perhaps through cygwin or cmd.exe)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you install ruby-debug-ide with DevKit?

Check [this article](http://www.rubytips.org/2011/12/20/installing-ruby-on-windows-7-ruby-1-9-x-guide/) for setup debug in Aptana. Although Aptana is base on eclipse,
I'm not sure if this can work. Wish you good luck.

And you have to require environment.rb at the top of the file to be debugged also.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version you have installed. The Ruby 1.92 environment is compatible with 64 bit. If yes, then check the Eclipse too - whether it is of compatible for a 64-bit machine as it sounds a bit like a conflict problem.